# Run method of a generic type

Tags: java, generics, methods

I  am not sure how to run a method of the generic type Point. Suppose the following classes

```
class Point1 {
      double x, y;
      public Point1 (double x_, double y_) {x=x_; y = y_;}
      public double getX() {return x;}
      public double getF1() {return x;}
}

class Point2 {
      double lat, lon;
      public Point2 (double lat_, double lon_) {lat = lat_; lon = lon_;}
      public double getLat(){return lat;}
      public double getF1() {return lat;}
}
```

sharing the same method getF1() and a method

```
public <Point> void test(List<Point> points) {
  for (Point point:points) 
      double x = point.getF1();   //Error Can not find symbol getF1()
}

public static void main (String [args]) {
   List <Point1> points = new ArrayList<>();
   test(points);
}
```

How to run the method getF1() associated with the Point1 type for the generic type Point (Point = Point1)? Is it possible to use the interface

```
public interface ICoord {
    double f();
```

and

```
public <Point> void test(List<Point> points, ICoord function) {
  for (Point point:points) 
      double x = point.function.f();
}
```

Comment: `Point1` and `Point2` would have to have some common superclass or interface to be able to refer to them generically.

Comment: What is `Point`? Don't see its definition.

Comment: @Sabir: here Point = Point1

Comment: Btw.: You're using an odd compiler. The comment (i.e. compiler error) should say "variable declaration not allowed here".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does look like you're just missing the definition of `Point` here.

```
public interface Point {
    double getF1();
}
```

This also means that each of your `Point` classes would have to implement this interface:

```
public class Point1 implements Point { }
public class Point2 implements Point { }
```

...and then you can use it, but you wouldn't need the generic parameter at all.

```
public void test(List<Point> points) {
  for (Point point: points) {
      double x = point.getF1();
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the comment in the loop, it could be misleading ;)

Comment: @AxelH:  Good catch; if you do see something like that in an answer, don't be shy about suggesting an edit.  I'd have approved that one.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to extract the `getF1()` method:

```
private interface PointWithF1 {
    public double getF1();
}

private static class Point1 implements PointWithF1 {
    // ...
}

private static class Point2 implements PointWithF1 {
    // ...
}
```

Then you can define a bound generic type:

```
public <Point extends PointWithF1> void test(List<Point> points) {
      for (Point point : points) {
          double x = point.getF1();  //Okay now
      }
}
```

But, then, you can simply use the interface too:

```
public void test(List<PointWithF1> points) {
      for (PointWithF1 point : points) {
          double x = point.getF1();  //Okay now
      }
}
```

So the point is (no pun intended) that java generics cannot do all those compile-time type checking as C++ templates. You have to be very specific with the generic types too.